# Using the chebychev inequality in the absence of st.dev but known max value

Tags: probability, upper-lower-bounds

A random variable X takes the maximum value of 80, and has a mean equal to 50. Give the best upper bound on P(X<=20).

So is it possible to use the Chebychev inequality here. Note that both values are 30 away from the mean. So is it correct to say that because P(X>=80) = 0 , then because P(X<=20) involves a similar calculation (because both values are 30 away from the mean), it would follow that P(X<=20) = 0  as well.

NOTE: We do not have the distribution of the RV.

Comment: "So is it possible to use the Chebychev inequality here." Erm, no, **why** would it be?

Comment: (There are r.v.'s satisfying the assumptions which are not even in $L^2$, i.e. do not have a standard deviation. How do you expect to apply Chebyshev's inequality?)

Comment: Either of these three inequalities have to be used: Markov, Chebychev and Chernoff. Since Markov inequality is pretty loose here and the chernoff can only be used for RV's that take the values between 0 and 1, I asked for Chebychev. Do you know another way to get a good upper bound?

Comment: You can only use Markov, that's the only one among the three inequalities you list which can apply here given the assumptions.

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Chebyshev's inequality here, as you don't even know whether $X$ is square integrable (i.e., $X$ may not even *have* a standard deviation). *(If you want, I can provide an example of such thing.)*

So, among the three inequalities you list (Markov, Chebyshev, Chernoff), the only one applicable is the weakest, Markov. Using it on the non-negative r.v. $Y = 80-X$ which has expectation $30$, you get
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X\leq 20\} = \mathbb{P}\{Y\geq 60\} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[Y]}{60} = \boxed{\frac{1}{2}}\,.
$$

Note further that this bound **cannot be improved** without further assumptions, as shown by the following example: $X$ taking value $80$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, and value $20$ with probability  $\frac{1}{2}$.